# Is there a real version of "Understanding People's Feelings" series (the book series Sai reads)?

Tags: naruto, resources

The character Sai, reads a book which has stuff like

> The bond between 2 people increases when you give them a nickname.

And

> When a woman feeds you, it is a clear sign that she likes you.

I want to read this book if it has a real version, or something close to it.

Comment: if you frequently hang around sites like 9gag there are post with things like that, so i think there has to be a book from someone who gathered all those and put them into a book. Try searching for a book on psychological lifehacks.

Comment: Sai reads many books. Therefore the sort of info he gains about people and interactions is not through a single source (in this case, a book). And most likely, the books shown in the series are just Naruto series exclusive. And mostly compiles of general facts about social interaction and bonding.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin *"And mostly compiles of general facts about social interaction and bonding"* so then Tsunade must really really like Jiraiya after feeding him that knuckle sandwitch that almost killed him

Comment: @Memor-X: like I said, ***general** facts about social..*. Jiraiya's pervy nature called for that punch. Also, in the end, we find out that Tsunade did really like him a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the book Sai reads is to make the fact that he doesn't know anything about human emotions more pronounced. It's to also show the fact that he takes his position as being an information gatherer into play. He tests them on the field, and treats finding his emotions like a mission.

Answer (score 0):

He’s reading a manga- as pointed out by Sakura in episode 72; the point is that the show Naruto is trying to help people (and other mangas) understand human emotion. Like literally watch the show/ read Naruto manga and understand that the show is getting across that we are all different and suffering and lonely and want to be acknowledged. Each character hints at different stereotypes of people and understanding them. There are books like what you are looking for but there is also a show called Naruto- think of the show as a life lesson and not an anime and you learn a lot about life